# Flutter webview with multiple links

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

I am trying to combine `Webview` with Native UI design. I've done a native UI and upon clicking on the `InkWell`, it will redirect to a specific html page. I am now stuck with all `InkWell` opening the same url, is there any other way I can redirect? For now I am stuck with one `Webview` displaying a single url. I will need to have about 40 different urls. For example,  `"https://example.com/data1.html"`, `"https://example.com/data2.html"`, and `"https://example.com/data3.html"`
Thank you!

**Code**

```
...

child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          buildCalc('img/O1-resize.png','O1'),
                          buildCalc('img/O2-resize.png', 'O2'),
                          buildCalc('img/O3-resize.png', 'O3'),
                          buildCalc('img/O4-resize.png', 'O4'),
                          buildCalc('img/O5-resize.png', 'O5')
                        ]
                        )
...

Widget buildCalc(String imgPath, String topic){
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, right:10.0, top:10.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Opticsdata()),);
        },
        child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Hero(
                    tag: imgPath,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(imgPath),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 75.0,
                      width: 75.0,
                      )
                    
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width:10.0),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          topic,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                ],
              )
              ),
           /* IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: (){},
            )*/
          ],
        )
        ),
      );
  }
}



...


class Opticsdata extends StatefulWidget { 
  @override 
  _OpticsState createState() => _OpticsState(); 

} 
  
class _OpticsState extends State { 
  
  TextEditingController controller=TextEditingController(); 
  FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin= FlutterWebviewPlugin(); 
  var url= "https://example.com/data1.html"; 
  
  @override 
  void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged wvs) {}); 
  } 
   
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return WebviewScaffold( 
      url: url, 
      withZoom: true, 
      hidden: true, 
      useWideViewPort: true,
      
      // initialChild: Container( 
      //   child:Center(child: Text("Loading"),) 
      // ), 
      
    ); 
  } 
}
```

**EDIT WORKING CODE BELOW FOR ANYONE WHO NEEDS IT**
Below is a working example and it is much simpler to understand.I used a `StreamBuilder` and used the declared data from `sites` to build the `ListView` with title, url, image.

```
 final data = sites;
```

```
...
child: StreamBuilder<List<WebSite>>(           
            initialData: data,
            builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListTile(
                   contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0,left: 20.0,bottom:10.0),
                    leading:  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),//or 15.0
                    child: Container(
                    width: 60,height: 60,
                    child: Image.asset(snapshot.data[i].imageurl,fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                    
                  ),
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[i].name),
                  onTap: () {
                    print(snapshot.data[i].url);
                    } 
...
```

```
class WebSite {
  final String name;
  final String url;
  final String imageurl;

  WebSite(this.name, this.url, this.imageurl);
}
```

```
final sites = [
   WebSite('title1', 'https://example.com/data1.html','img1'),
   WebSite('title2', 'https://example.com/data2.html','img2'),
   WebSite('title3', 'https://example.com/data3.html','img3'),
   ...
];
```

Here, I declare the title name for the `ListView` with url and image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

First create a data model where you will keep all you image related Data.

```
 class Data{
  String image;
  String id;
  Data({this.id,this.image});
}
```

Then initialise with image data

```
List<Data> data = [Data(id: '01',image: 'img/O1-resize.png'),Data(id: '01',image: 'img/O1-resize.png'),];
```

change your List view

```
Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return buildCalc(data[index],context);
                },
                itemCount: data.length,
              ),
            )
```

refactor this method.

```
     Widget buildCalc(Data data,context){
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, right:10.0, top:10.0),
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Opticsdata(data: data,)),);
        },
        child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Hero(
                        tag: data.id,
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage(data.image),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          height: 75.0,
                          width: 75.0,
                        )

                    ),
                    SizedBox(width:10.0),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          data.id,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )
            ),
            /* IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: (){},
            )*/
          ],
        )
    ),
  );
}
```

Modify your Opticsdata Page.

```
class Opticsdata extends StatelessWidget{

  final Data data;

  const Opticsdata({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  But right now I am stuck with the buildCalc method not being able to generate unique urls. I have changed the `return Container();` to a webview method to display urls.

Comment: Is there a proper way to see what is the data value passed over at the Opticsdata page?